# Cycles is not rendering armature object

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, armature

I have this stick figure kind of guy doing a dance. He is clearly there in solid mode and texture mode:

[image: Solid Mode]

[image: Texture Mode]

But when I go into render mode or just try to render an image, it's gone:

[image: Render Mode]
[image: Rendered]

I can't for the life of me figure out what inconsequential silly mistake I am making. I probably just need another pair of eyes to look at it.

Here is a link to the .blend file. Don't judge me, I'm trying to teach myself rigging and animation: http://speedy.sh/E9MH4/DANCE-2.blend

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend or a screenshot of your material setup? I don't see anything in those screenshots which would cause this..

Comment: Just added a download link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [dupliverts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliVerts) (*Properties > Object > Duplication*) enabled on the armature.

Disable them, and then everything works as expected:

[image]

An object with dupliverts enabled renders instances of itself on the vertices of child objects.

As your object has no child objects, it just disappears.